# How to install NodeJs older version (0.10.40)

Tags: node.js, meteor, centos

I need to deploy meteor app. Meteor require Node `0.10.40`

Doing

```
sudo yum install -y epel-release curl
curl --fail -sSL -o setup-nodejs https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup
sudo bash setup-nodejs
sudo yum install -y nodejs gcc-c++ make
```

gave me `0.10.43`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get 0.10.40 version [here](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v0.10.40/)